why not leave the question and answers and votes in place attributed to anonymous when a User is deleted
I have notices that when a user is deleted the votes and answers seem to get deleted, not sure about the questions. However, I have seen at other SE, they retain the questions and answers delegated to an anonymous user. Why is that not being done here at Quant SE?
It degrades the quality of the Q&A thread. 
If possible these should be retroactively be reinstated for already deleted users.
I hope an admin is looking at this and what do you guys think?

Can you point to an example? As far as I know a user could delete his stuff and then delete his account (which indeed is very annoying) but this shouldn't happen automatically.

I will search and post later. However, even deleting his own stuff should not be allowed once posted. People depend on things they have seen there to come back to later and it destroys the continuity.

No disagreement here... Thank you and we'll see what we can do.

when (auto) deleting users the votes are removed too, probably should not.
